# How To Add <br /> In The End Of Every Line In <pre> Tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pre

I am sharing codes in my WordPress blog but I don't want to use any plugin or third party to host and format my codes. I add codes and use `<pre></pre>` tags around it but the problem is that when someone copy it then all line break disappear and the pasted code becomes in one line that sometime confuse the user or some time stop working.

So now is there any trick to add line break or `<br/>` in the end of every line of `<pre></pre>` tag only using PHP or JavaScript.

You can see some error DEMO's here...

- [How To Add List Style V1-Optimized Blogger Posts In Blogspot?](http://www.exeideas.com/2014/07/list-style-v1-optimized-blogger-posts.html)
- [How To Add Grid Style V1-Optimized Blogger Posts In Blogspot?](http://www.exeideas.com/2014/07/grid-style-v1-optimized-blogger-posts.html)

and many more of my posts have this error.

To check this error, Just copy the `<pre></pre>` tag codes and paste it anywhere and see that there will be no line break as code shows on blog. How to fix it?

Comment: http://php.net/nl2br?

Comment: `</br>` that should be `<br/>` syntax-speaking. As per pre-edited post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27605280/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, Sorry... :(

Comment: @MarcB Yes, something like this but How can I apply it on my blog?

Comment: @MZeinstra Err... that's what I said ;-)

Comment: have you tried putting `\n` after each line in `<pre>`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol I saw it to late.. You're right ;)

Comment: @MuhammadHassan If you're looking for having clean well-formatted HTML in PHP, then using and for example `echo $var1 . "<br/>" . "\n"; echo $var2 . "<br/>" . "\n"; echo $var3 . "<br/>" . "\n";` will produce HTML in lines vertically aligned, producing clean HTML. As opposed to  `echo $var1 . "<br/>"; echo $var2 . "<br/>"; echo $var3 . "<br/>";` which will be all in one LONG line in HTML source.

Comment: @gellu No. I just add the code and wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tag...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now How can I edit all my 1000's of posts... :(

Comment: Hm... good question. You could try something like `echo "<div id='x'>" . nl2br(posts) . "</div>";` I don't know Wordpress, but if you have some type of wrapper, you could probably get away in doing something like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got my problem and its solved. Answer shared below and Please don't laugh at me. :D

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Hey that's great, glad to hear it. You don't see me laughing ;-) *Cheers mate!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in the script sharethis.com. Try disabling "Measure copy and shares of your website's content" in http://www.sharethis.com/get-sharing-tools/

Comment: Dude. You are hell AWESOME... Thanks a lot to fix my problem... I am also confusing that all syntax are official then why I have error and you did it... (y)

Comment: Ah, another happy ending.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I simply deleted there share button/javascript and its done. (y)

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Right on Muhammad. Sometimes it's the simplest things that get the job done ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes this is why we are HUMANS... :-D

Comment: @MuhammadHassan You said it cousin ;-)